# How to solve this system of equations (one plus and the other times)?

Tags: systems-of-equations, quadratics

I have come up with the following system of equations 
$$a+b=1,$$
and
$$a \times b = -1.$$
I know that the solution is $a = \frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{5})$ and $b = \frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{5})$.

But how to find such a solution? What is such a system of equations called?

Comment: By Vieta's relations, $\,a,b\,$ are the roots of $\,x^2 - (a+b)x+ab\,x = 0 \iff x^2-x-1=0\,$. `I know that the solution is ...` Since the system is symmetric in the two variables, you can swap $\,a,b\,$ and get the other solution.

Comment: $b = (1-a).$  $$a \times b= -1 \iff  a\times (1-a) = -1 \iff 1+ a-a^2 = 0\iff a^2-a-1 = 0$$  Use the quadratic formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With $$b=-\frac{1}{a}$$ we get
$$a-\frac{1}{a}=1$$ multiplying by $$a\neq 0$$ we get
$$a^2-a-1=0$$ Can you solve this equation?

Comment: That's great! Yeah! I could solve it. :-)

Comment: Fine, a nice day for you!